# How to test if 2 SVG Paths intersect at more than 1 point and if path1 includes path2 using snapsvg

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I need help about the best way to test if
two paths intersect at more than 1 point
    consecutively
    not consecutively
path1 include path2
path1 = path2.

I also need explanation about 
 the meaning of properties of the result object of the  (http://jsbin.com/pawoduho/5/edit)

```
Snap.path.intersection(path1, path2)
Snap.path.getPointAtLength(path, length )
```

Thanks in advance

T. Kia Ntoni

Comment: Wouldn't checking if the array length of .intersection(p1,p2) is > 1 ?  And for inclusion, use getPointAtLength, and traverse through checking if the results are the same for each point ?

Comment: Sorry the last bit would be a check for them being the same, but you could probably do something similar.

Comment: @ian Inclusion check suggested does not work. Please see de console log of this bin [link](http://jsbin.com/jokugata/2/edit)